# Declaring C# variable with and without Constructor

Tags: c#

I have this doubt in my mind for a very long time. May be this is the right forum to ask..

Is there any difference between the two types of variable declaration in C#. If so what is the difference and which is the best practice.

```
  DataTable dt;
```

vs

```
  DataTable dt=new Datatable();
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate (which I will look for in a minute) but in the second one, you assign a value

Comment: first one is creating a variable that can hold a datatable, the second creates the variable and instantiates it also.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: [Related (See Reed Copsey's answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952503/c-sharp-variable-initialization-question).. still can't find duplicate (yet)

Comment: [Another related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511963/declaring-value-types-by-using-operator-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one you are only declaring and in second you declaring and initializing.
If you use any instance of a class without initializing, then you will get `null` reference exception as [`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

if DataTable  is a struct they are the same

if not `DataTable dt;` means create empy reference to a `DataTable` named dt;
'new Datatable();' means init the reference using `Datatable` object from the garbage collector

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best practice is to always initialize the variable in the constructor and never in the declaration. This is for consistency mainly, if you want to see how a type is initialized you should always only have to look in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The first dt can hold a DataTable or object that inherites `DataTable`, the value of the first dt will be `null` after the first one is done.

The second dt can hold a `DataTable` or object that inherites DataTable, You initiated it with empty constructor of `DataTable` therefore it will not be `null`.

"Best Parctice" is depends on what you want to do with dt.
for example, if you have a method on the next line that returns a new initiated `DataTable` it is not nessesery to initiate an instance that will not be used.